# Button click validation in Angular2

Tags: angular

```html
<form>
  <div class="ui-input-group">
    <input #model="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Name*" name="visitorName" [(ngModel)]="visitorName">
    <span class="input-bar"></span>
    <div  *ngIf="model.errors && (modeltitle.dirty || model.touched)"  style="color: red">
       Required
    </div>

   <button class="icon-btn" id="addVisitor" title="Add" (click)="addVisitor()">
   <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Button click should be disabled if the input field is blank,
How can I achieve that ?Currently validation message is not being displayed, what is wrong with the above code.

This like default validation message :
[image]

Comment: You should see Form validation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your need? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <div class="ui-input-group">
        <input #model="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Name*"
               name="visitorName" [(ngModel)]="visitorName">
        <span class="input-bar"></span>
        <div *ngIf="model.errors && (modeltitle.dirty || model.touched)" style="color: red">Required
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="icon-btn" id="addVisitor" title="Add" (click)="addVisitor()"
            [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can I use default form validation , instead of this message ? <div  *ngIf="model.errors && (modeltitle.dirty || model.touched)"  style="color: red">Required</div>

Comment: @user630209 what do you mean with **default form validation**?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <div class="ui-input-group">
        <input #model="ngModel" 
                type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name*"
               name="visitorName" [(ngModel)]="visitorName">
        <span class="input-bar"></span>
        <div *ngIf="model.errors && (modeltitle.dirty || model.touched)" 
         style="color: red">Required
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="icon-btn" id="addVisitor" title="Add" (click)="addVisitor()" 
    [disabled]="!f.valid"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
</form>
```

If you don't want the message `Please fill out this field`, remove the require attribute in your `input` and add novalidate in your form like this

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm"> ...
```

Comment: Why to use ngModel inside form. You need to use formControl.

Comment: @YoavSchniederman the code provided is using template-driven forms that's why. If it is reactive-form, formControl should have been used

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want native validation. As of Angular 4, `novalidate` is set by default. So now you have to explicitly tell Angular to provide it. We can do that with

```
ngNativeValidate
```

in the form tag.

Furthermore, you also have to make some changes to your form. You need to make the button of type `submit`, otherwise when you click submit when form is not valid, the method `addVisitor()` will be fired anyway. But if your button is of `type="submit"` the method will not be fired. This also means, that you should set `(ngSubmit)="addVisitor()"` in the form tag. So change your form to this:

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate (ngSubmit)="addVisitor()">
  <div class="ui-input-group">
    <input #model="ngModel" type="text" class="form-control" required 
           placeholder="Name*" name="visitorName" [(ngModel)]="visitorName">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How I can call ngNativeValidate validator function without submit. I mean with different button?